# Exercise 13: Parameters, Unpacking, Variables - Totally lost

Tags: python

I have got to section 13 of Learn Python The Hard Way. Having followed all the rules and directions given to get this far.  I am not a programmer and do often hit sticking points where I need step by step guidance.

I have done everything in this section, and I have a named my file **section12.py** and saved to my desktop.  I am trying to make this run, but not really sure how to make it run.

This is the script as I have typed it:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

When I run the programme, I get the following message:

```
========= RESTART: C:\Users\Photo Design Studio\Desktop\section12.py =========

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Photo Design Studio\Desktop\section12.py", line 3, in <module>
    script, first, second, third = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Based on the information provided, can someone offer me step by step guidance on how to run this?

Comment: What are you even talking about?

Comment: Open the command line or terminal, depending on your OS, change directory to the one with that file typing `cd [full path to directory]` [Enter], and then type `python section12.py` [Enter], this should make it run.

Comment: Is this section 13 of _Learn Python the Hard Way_? You may wish to read [LPTHW Complaints](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints)...

Comment: Also, you would want to use the [StackOverflow search to look for similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=argv+more+than+1+value+to+unpack)

Comment: You are supposed to give command line arguments to the program. That is, you run the program as `section12.py something other here`.

Comment: This might be a silly question but where do I run the programme?  Where do I type section12.py something other here, to make this work.  Please bear in mind I have no programming knowledge.  I am sure  will kick myself as the answer will be so basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the error is on line 3 `script, first, second, third = argv`.  argv is a way of seeing what extra information is being given to your program.  When you call your program with `python section12.py`, argv is defined as `("section12.py",)`.  When you call your program with `python section12.py 65`, argv is defined as `("section12.py", "65")`.  When you say `script, first, second, third = argv`, you are assigning a name to each item of argv.  If you call your program with just `python section12.py`, argv has only one item, but you are trying to assign four variables to it.  The error is that it doesn't have enough items to assign to those variables.  To fix it, try calling your program with something like this: `python section12.py myfirst mysecond mythird`.  Fiddle around with it; have fun!

Comment: I add python section12.py myfirst mysecond mythird into Python Shell GUI and it gives me a syntax error.  Am I typing in the right place??

Comment: @GinjaNinja: You need to type `python section12.py myfirst mysecond mythird` at the command prompt, **not** in the Python interpreter.

Comment: @PM 2Ring thank your for your input.  I have done this; I still get an error: 'python' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  The file is stored on my desktop, if thats any help.

Comment: Hi @PM 2Ring, I have found a YouTube video on it.  Hopefully I will be able to sort....Nightmare!  Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Since you're using Windows, try just `section12.py myfirst mysecond mythird`.

Comment: Is there any way I can post a picture of the command prompt?  I appear to have Python correctly installed; however, when I try to run the program with or without the word python I receive a syntax error.  It says   ** File "<stdin>", line 1 python abc.py 1 2 3.  I have changed the file name, as tired of typing it!

Comment: @GinjaNinja you're trying to run the file from the Python prompt. You need to run that command from the regular command prompt (`cmd`).

Comment: Hi MattDMo, How would you type this?  I have tried a few ways; still getting error.

Comment: At long last managed to sort the problem.  Thanks for the input guys